# Как применить частицу "бы" в диалоге?

Tags: частица

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше применить частицу "бы" в диалоге

— Если бы не вы, неизвестно, сколько еще мы не смогли бы открыть эти двери.

— Но это, вероятно, мог сделать бы любой

Мы бы не смогли или мы не смогли бы?
Мог бы сделать или мог сделать бы?

Answer (score 0):

Перемещение *бы* переносит акцент(сомнение) на другое слово:

Мы бы *не смогли* - акцент на *не смогли*.

Мы не смогли бы ... - акцент на сделать - не смогли бы *открыть*.

Теоретически можно же хоть после почти каждого слова поставить бы:

Мы бы не смогли бы открыть бы эти бы двери(бы?).

На самом деле фраза без бы звучит так:

> — Если бы не вы, неизвестно, сколько еще мы не смогли бы открыть эти двери.

— Ежели не ваша помощь, неведомо, как долго нам находиться при закрытых дверях.

Похоже на древнерусский диалект). *Бы* дает акцентуацию будущего и прошлого времени.